# PF datatable value and filteredValue - best practise

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

I should have asked this question way earlier but now I am really tired of dodging around this problem:

I have a normal datatable like
`<p:dataTable id="dt1" var="tVar" value="#{mrBean.queriedElements}" filteredValue="#{mrBean.filteredElements}" ...`

Now in addition to the primefaces filters, I made my own panelGrid in which you can apply filters to the data base which work before any PF action.
The following lists exist: queriedElements which holds all the data that is returned after my personal filter applied and filteredElements which is needed for primefaces datatable filtering. In addition, I am not exactly sure whether I need an element list that represents all the data from the database. If no personal filter is applied, queriedElements = allElements.

The datatable displays a lot of information on the objects contained and you can change these objects via a dialog. I want the following:

- When saved, update all changes made to the selectedElement
- When cancelled, revert all changes in the datatable (I dont use a temporary object that is edited but the very object from the list)
- When closing the dialog, remember all filters and paginator position

What is the best practise to do so and how can I avoid redundant code for queriedElements and filteredElements (in case I must iterate through it to change it explicitly in addition to database merges)? I found the first attribute for pagination, but I'm not really sure how to use it properly combined with my other requirements. My main problem is that the datatable almost never displays the right values if I don't refetch from database.

PF 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why PF 4.0 doesn't do this by itself, but something that worked for me can be found at http://www.brainhemorage.com/?p=258

Although I had to replaced the lines

```
  ValueExpression filterBy = column.getValueExpression("filterBy");
   String filterField = null;
   if (filterBy != null)
      filterField = table.resolveStaticField(filterBy);
   String filterId = column.getContainerClientId(context) + separator + "filter";
   String filterValue = params.containsKey(filterId) && !table.isReset() ? params.get(filterId) : 
           table.getFilters().get(filterField); // <-- and here, was ""
   String filterStyleClass = column.getFilterStyleClass();
```

by

```
String filterId = column.getContainerClientId(context) + separator + "filter";
String filterValue = params.containsKey(filterId) && !table.isReset() ? params.get(filterId) : 
            table.getFilters().get(column.getFilterBy());
```

because getValueExpression always returned null.

Although this doesn't answer my question about the BP, this will surely help others with the filteredValue problem.